# Cannot send String properly with ESP-NOW

Tags: string, struct, esp8266

I'm trying to send a string from device 1 to device 2 (both are Wemos D1 Mini ESP8266) on the same breadboard, but it keeps giving me a strange response on device 2.

What I send:

```cpp
strcpy(myData.a, "THIS IS A CHAR");
myData.b = random(1,20);
myData.c = 1.2;
myData.d = "Halo apa kabar semua";
myData.e = false;
```

What I receive:

> Bytes received: 56
> Char: THIS IS A CHAR
> Int: 7
> Float: 1.20
> String: ??????????

What should I do? I have used this code as '[reference](https://randomnerdtutorials.com/esp-now-esp8266-nodemcu-arduino-ide/)', even copied it completely, but still got like that.

Comment: Try strcpy(myData.d, "Halo apa kabar semua"); instead of myData.d = "Halo apa kabar semua";

Comment: but strcpy is for char, not for string. i need myData.d still on string

Comment: It works for myData.a, why do you think it won't work for myData.d?

Comment: because myData.a is in char, while myData.d is string. based on the reference link, it does can send data in string, but why i cannot?

Answer (score 1):

My tip is not quite suitable for your case with the structure.
But you can use my approach
and redo for your needs.
Master send String like this:

```
  String helloStr = "Hello World";
  uint8_t *buffer = (uint8_t*) helloStr.c_str();
  size_t sizeBuff = sizeof(buffer) * helloStr.length();
  esp_now_send(peer_addr, buffer, sizeBuff);
```

and the Slave get the String like this:

```
// callback when data is recv from Master
void OnDataRecv(const uint8_t *mac_addr, const uint8_t *data, int data_len) {
   char* buff = (char*) data;
  String buffStr = String(buff);
  Serial.println(buffStr);
}
```

Comment: `size_t sizeBuff = sizeof(buffer) * helloStr.length();`  I think `buffer` is just a pointer address = 4 bytes that is a starting point of byte array data ("Hello World").   So I think the `sizeBuff` is actually more like `size_t sizeBuff = sizeof(uint8_t) * helloStr.length();` which is equal to "helloStr.length()" anyways.

Answer (score 0):

The `struct` used for `myData` is:

```cpp
typedef struct struct_message {
  char a[32];
  int b;
  float c;
  String d;
  bool e;
} struct_message;
```

You are not giving myData.d a `string` object, but a `char[]`, like you give `myData.a`.

Try giving it Arduino's version of a `string` *object*:

```cpp
String str = "Halo apa kabar semua"; 
myData.d = str;
```

If that doesn't work, show us the compiler warnings and errors.